# Knockout.js array append more objects

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am loading data with Ajax, for initial load, I could bind all data by using this to observableArry:

```
            success: function (result) {
                var mappedData = $.map(result.d, function (item) {
                    return new Applicant(item);
                });
                self.Applicants(mappedData);
            }
```

The question is when I want to load more to the array, I know how to add one, but what if the next load would be more than 1 object, and I want to bind to array, how could I do that?

self.Applicants.push(mappedData); won't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: After posting this found a way: ko.utils.arrayPushAll(self.Applicants, mappedData);

Answer (score 3):

If you need to add a bunch of objects to your observable array, I would just set the whole array to its current contents, concated with the new object.

The following should work:

```
self.Applicants(self.Applicants().concat(mappedData));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(self.Applicants(), mappedData);
self.Applicants.valueHasMutated();
```

For general tips & tricks on working with observable arrays, be sure to check out [Ryan Niemeyer's article on it](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html).

Comment: I *think* you'd have to manually tell self.Applicants to do a notification of its subscribers after that.

Comment: Ahh - shouldn't `call` be `apply`?  Otherwise aren't you just pushing an entire array onto the end of this array?

Comment: @AdamRackis: It's been a long day. Thanks (again)